# How did Stack Overflow succeed when it was starting out?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community

How did Stack Overflow get started?  How did the Stack Overflow operators get so many experts to participate during the initial stage?

Answer (score 8):

Listen to the podcast (starting with episode 1).

Comment: Where do we find that podcast?

Comment: http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html (see link at bottom of page)

Comment: How sad. I listened to 1 minutes and with the dumb jokes and everything just could not support it longuer. I hate podcasts.

Comment: @iznogood podcast 1 is a bit shaky as it was the first. Try sampling some slightly later ones.

Comment: @Jeff Will do. I admit I overreacted yesterday.

Comment: The full list of the 87 podcasts, including the first 7 can found at https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4

Answer (score 7):

> How did the Stack Overflow operators get so many experts to participate during the initial stage?

The two founders, [Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) and [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky), both had software development blogs with a huge following, [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) and [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/), respectively. This allowed seeding Stack Overflow with a lot of users.

Comment: Good answer, but it leaves out what I suspect is a critical distinction: those audiences allowed seeding SO with a lot of __good__ users.